# Two variants of same domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have two variants of the same domain name registered through a registrar. I have one site that is hosted on AWS.

To point the variation of the name to the same site do I either:

1) Copy the DNS records at the registrar of the original site and make the duplicate records the same

2) Make a new hosted zone with an alias pointing to the same site and point the variation to that new hosted zone

Comment: Can you explain the question further? What do you mean by two variants of same domain name

Comment: Assuming that AWS Route 53 is your DNS provider. You would need a new hosted zone and you would need to create records that point the variant toward a server that will redirect users to your primary website.

Comment: I have two domains - 

website.com and websites.com 

my DNS is managed by a site that I bought the domains from initially - since then I launched a site on AWS. 

Website.com is already setup in route53 and is a live site, but I want to connect websites.com to the same site

Answer (score 0):

Using AWS I created an S3 bucket that was a static 301 redirect to the original site. Details here https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-domain-route-53/